# Creating MarkDown documents in ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, markdown

I'm trying to dynamically generate some MarkDown formatted documents, with header fields of arbitrary lengths.

```
I want to have a title of arbitrary length underlined like this
---------------------------------------------------------------

This should work to
-------------------
```

The code I came up with to do this in my ERB views.

```
<%= @title %>
<%= @title.length.times.map{"-"}.join %>
```

Is there a more efficient way to make this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use multiplication. Multiplying a String by a Fixnum will produce a new String where the original String appears the Fixnum of times.

```
"-" * @title.length #=> "---------------"
```

[Documentation for String#*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-2A)

Warning: Make sure you put the String first or else you will get a `TypeError: String can't be coerced into Fixnum` since that would be calling `Fixnum#*` instead of `String#*`.